# Linking error LNK2001: unresolved symbol glePolyCylinder

Tags: linker

I'm trying to use the [GLE tubing and extrusion library](http://www.linas.org/gle/) for a personal OpenGL project but I'm stuck with the following error:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl glePolyCylinder(int,double (* const)[3],float (* const)[3],double)" (?glePolyCylinder@@YAXHQAY02NQAY02MN@Z)
```

I'm using VS Express 2013 to compile. I've created an empty project and compiled the GLE source code into a .lib file, then added this .lib file to the linker dependencies in my main project (Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional dependencies) along with the other .lib files I'm using, and I've included the header file with:

```
#include "gle-3.0.0\src\gle.h"
```

but I still keep getting the error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to link the lib

Comment: Doesn't adding the lib to the linker options, as I already have done,  "link" the lib? Otherwise what's the way do correctly do that?

Comment: Did you also add the path the to the library to VC++ Directories -> Library Directories?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are including the header, but not linking to the library.

Do you have something like this at the top of your code?

```
#pragma comment (lib, "gle32")
```

Please see the documentation for more info on pragmas:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things to do when you are going to include a 3rd party lib in VS.

First, in your Project properties (Right click the project name in VS) select properties at the bottom of the menu. In the dialog, go to Configuration Properties => Linker => All

Under All options, scroll up to Additional Dependencies and add the lib by adding gle32.lib; before kernel32.lib.Options. [image: VS Properties Dialog]

After that, you will have to append the gle32.lib path to Additional Library Directories, you can give it the full path for testing purpose and when it links correctly use the macros to build a relative path for it. It's documented in the additional dialog that you can pop up.

Now, try to build and see if it links correctly. If it does not link correctly still, make sure to check your paths and the name of the lib etc. And, make sure to verify that you are building the new project that consumes the gle32.lib with the same architecture, eg. 32bit libraries for 32bit solution build configurations. You can't mix 32 and 64bit libs.

As @aledalgrande points out, you can use the #pragma comment as well, but that still requires that you have your library search paths setup correctly hence why I recommend that you start with the Project Properties as described above.

Another side note. Don't use backslash (\) in the include directive since Windows and VS do handle forward slashes (/) for you it makes it easier to move the code to other OSes, and it's also a sanity thing to make sure you're not triggering any unintended string escaping.

Good luck!